# Will the COP of 10 stage cascaded refrigeration / AC system be high?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer

Consider a cascaded refrigeration/AC system that has ten stages, with each stage cooling by only 5°C/9°F.  For example: Cooling takes place from 40°C to -10°C over ten stages. Each stage has a high COP. For example: Carnot refrigeration efficiency for cooling from 40°C to 35°C is about 61.

Off course, having ten stages will mean ten heat exchangers and compressors- but focusing only on COP, will such a system be much more efficient?

Comment: 10 devices so losses for 10 devices added…

Comment: Multiplied efficiencies in series.  Fun thing about COP is that it can be greater than 1, unlike efficiency, however it's all about what you care about- what happens to the COP when you have to generate the sink yourself from another stage? Pretend you are moving 1J from your inner stage all the way to your no-cost sink through all those stages - what did it cost you?

Answer (score 1):

Coefficient of Performance (COP) = energy moved/energy spent

So if I move 1J through N stages, I've moved 1J, but incurred the spend of N stages.

Supposing I have N stages in series, each with COP=C:

I incur 1/C J at each stage (C=1J/spend so spend = 1J/C)

Total spend is thus N times that so N/C J.

What I moved is still 1J.

So overall COP=1J/(N/C J) = C/N

In reality, you can expect COP to be even worse because some of the energy spent will seep into the main payload, costing the other stages to remove that energy as well.  Whether it is good to do depends on how many times over the COP will improve by having a lower temperature difference between source and sink.

In other words, if I put 10 entities at COP=2 in series, I get a resulting COP of 2/10 or .2.

If however the COP was 2 for the full temperature difference but shoots up to 20 when the difference is 1/10 of the full, then by putting 10 in series, I may at best get back to my COP of 2.

Answer (score 1):

COP for a fridge is limited by the source and sink temperatures, in your case Th=313, Tc=263, COPcooling<Tc/(Th-Tc) so COPcooling<5.26

It doesn't matter how many stages you have that is the absolute limit. In practice your pumps etc will leak heat back into the cooling side, so that limit is not feasible.